# Confusion with thread synchronization [pthreads]

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, rtos, qnx

I have had a problem threads for a long time. This code is supposed to have a worker thread increment the value of a shared integer while the main thread prints it out. However, I am not getting my expected output.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;
int shared_data = 0; //shared data


// Often shared data is more complex than just an int.
void* thread_function(void* arg)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // Access the shared data here.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        shared_data++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int i;
    void* exit_status;
    // Initialize the mutex before trying to use it.
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
    // Try to use the shared data.
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf ("\r for i= %d Shared integer 's value = %d\n", i, shared_data);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    printf("\n");
    pthread_join(thread, &exit_status);
    // Clean up the mutex when we are finished with it.
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I expect:

```
for i=0 Shared Integer 's value = 0
for i=1 Shared Integer 's value = 1 
for i=3 Shared Integer 's value = 2
...
for i=10 Shared Integer 's value =10
```

but the result is:

```
for i=0 Shared Integer 's value = 0
for i=1 Shared Integer 's value = 10
for i=3 Shared Integer 's value = 10
...
for i=10 Shared Integer 's value =10
```

so how can i resoleve this?

Comment: Please format your code with consistent and proper indentation to make it readable.

Comment: Then explain to us what part of your program do you think will sequence the output in the way you have described. You seem to assume that the main thread will get the lock, then a child thread, then the main thread, then a child thread, etc. There is no such guarantee.

Comment: The join on the first main iteration waits for the thread to complete, thus on the second ineration you get the end result of 10.

Comment: @NikolaiFetissov Thank you , i've edited the format of my code , in fact i was excpecting that the thread increments the value of the shared data , after that the loop in main print the value , from 0 to 10 , which not the case here

Comment: Why do devs so consistently misuse a mutex when two semaphores are needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thread and your worker thread are running concurrently. That is, getting those for loops to coincide with each other perfectly is nearly impossible without extra synchronization.

Your output is exactly what you should expect. The time taken to spawn the thread allows the main thread to print before the other thread changes the shared data. Then, the print takes so long that the other thread completely finishes with its loop and increments the shared data to 10 before the main thread can get to its second iteration.

<s>In a perfect world, this little hack using condition variables will get you what you want:</s>
**EDIT: condition variables were a bad idea for this. Here is working version that uses pseudo atomic variables and *doesn't* contain UB :)** :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t want_incr_mut;
pthread_mutex_t done_incr_mut;
int want_incr = 0;
int done_incr = 0;
int shared_data = 0; //shared data

// Not using atomics, so...

void wait_for_want_increment()
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&want_incr_mut);
        if (want_incr)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&want_incr_mut);
            return;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&want_incr_mut);
    }
}

void wait_for_done_incrementing()
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&done_incr_mut);
        if (done_incr)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&done_incr_mut);
            return;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&done_incr_mut);
    }
}


void done_incrementing()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&done_incr_mut);

    done_incr = 1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&want_incr_mut);
    want_incr = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&want_incr_mut);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&done_incr_mut);
}

void want_increment()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&want_incr_mut);

    want_incr = 1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&done_incr_mut);
    done_incr = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&done_incr_mut);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&want_incr_mut);
}

// Often shared data is more complex than just an int.
void* thread_function(void* arg)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        wait_for_want_increment();
        // Access the shared data here.
        shared_data++;
        done_incrementing();
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int i;
    void* exit_status;

    // Initialize the mutex before trying to use it.
    pthread_mutex_init(&want_incr_mut, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&done_incr_mut, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_function, NULL);

    // Try to use the shared data.
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("\r for i= %d Shared integer 's value = %d\n", i, shared_data);
        if (i == 10) break;

        want_increment();
        wait_for_done_incrementing();
    }
    printf("\n");
    pthread_join(thread, &exit_status);
    // Clean up the mutexes when we are finished with them.
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&want_incr_mut);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&done_incr_mut);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, we just tell the worker that we want an increment and wait for him to say he is done before we continue. Meanwhile, the worker waits for us to want an increment and tells us when he is done.

I also changed the main loop to go to ten because that is what I think you want.

Here is my output:

```
for i= 0 Shared integer 's value = 0
for i= 1 Shared integer 's value = 1
for i= 2 Shared integer 's value = 2
for i= 3 Shared integer 's value = 3
for i= 4 Shared integer 's value = 4
for i= 5 Shared integer 's value = 5
for i= 6 Shared integer 's value = 6
for i= 7 Shared integer 's value = 7
for i= 8 Shared integer 's value = 8
for i= 9 Shared integer 's value = 9
for i= 10 Shared integer 's value = 10
```

Comment: thank you first ,  but how could i resolve this problem ?

Comment: To be honest, you don't want to do this... However, you could use condition variables. You want the main thread to wait for the worker thread to be done with each increment before it prints, and you want the worker thread to continue once the main thread has signaled that it is done printing.

Comment: exactly that's what i want , it seems a little bit diffuclt right . .

Comment: Thank you , but i still have the same problem , it shows me now for i=0 shared Integer's value =0                                     for i=1 shared Integer's value=11 , for i=2 shared Integer's value=11 ... until i=10

Comment: @azert123 Hmm. I tested it on Windows with MinGW. Maybe there is a bug in my code that just happens to work here? Did you try copying my code exactly? I sounds like you only changed the loops to go to 10...

Comment: @azert123 I changed the first loop back to `<  10` so the shared variable is left at 10, but the code should have still printed the correct values if you copied it correctly.

Comment: @azert123 I just tested it on linux; it works fine. You must have copied it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for making This logic , first i was testing this on devc++ , also in QNX Momentic but the results were wrong , i'v tested this on codeBlocks and it worked perfectly , thank you so much (y)

Comment: @azert123 don't forget to mark as accepted if you are happy. Although, it is interesting that a different build environment gave different results...

Comment: with pleasur , for 100% :)

Comment: @azert123 I was using condition variables wrong, causing undefined behavior. That is why is sometimes worked and sometimes didn't. I have fixed it to where it works and only uses mutexes for simplicity.